# Diacritic Marks not render correctly in Web App when written with JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, localization, globalization

I have an MVC 4 application that I'm localizing. All the built-in resourcing and **Model** attributed content is appearing fine, but where I localized content written for *JQuery* the encoding appears wrong. Here is an example of how things render, note the red boxes... they should be the same word.

[image]

The problem appears to revolve around the below line of code in my **View**:

```
$("#FirstName").Watermark("@Resources.ApplicantGivenNameWatermark");
```

This *JQuery* essentially takes in a string and then writes it to the input when no other value has been supplied. Here is an abstract of that code:

```
$.fn.Watermark = function (text) {
    return this.each(
        function () {
            var input = $(this);
            map[map.length] = { text: text, obj: input };

            //Similar removal process lies here, this one also removes the style

            function insertMessage() {
                if (input.val().length == 0 || input.val() == text) {
                    input.val(text);
                    input.addClass("watermark");
                } else
                    input.removeClass("watermark")
            }

            input.focus(clearMessage);
            input.blur(insertMessage);
            input.change(insertMessage);

            insertMessage();
        }
    );
};
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this would be appreciated. As a side note, I've been able to reliably recreate this in a wide range of browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to put this at the begin of the function:

```
text=$('<span>'+text+'</span>').text();
```

Comment: @DrMolle That totally worked, can you explain what is happening under the covers and why this fix works?

Comment: The &#x234; is a entity , the unicode-notation for ê to be used in XML/HTML . The value-attribute of an input contains only CDATA, so the entity will not be parsed, you must parse it before you set the value. The suggested line will do it, it will create a span with the given HTML, and returns the text-data inside this span.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that Razor is built for outputting HTML, not Javascript. By default, it will encode all your strings with HTML entities - which aren't appropriate for Javascript strings.

You *could* use `@Html.Raw(Model.YourString)`, but that will give you other problems, such as not escaping quotation marks etc. (the standard Razor output does that by "accident").

If you're using .NET 4.0/MVC 3, you can use AjaxHelper's `JavaScriptStringEncode`, which returns an `IHtmlString` (meaning Razor won't entity-encode it) but also does the proper Javascript-specific escaping (including line breaks in the source string, which the standard Razor encoding won't "fix"):

```
$("#FirstName").Watermark(
   "@Ajax.JavaScriptStringEncode(Resources.ApplicantGivenNameWatermark")");
```

(Yeah, it turns rather verbose... but does have the advantage of fixing the problem at its root, rather than working around it through jQuery - you could of course make a helper with a short name which called `JavaScriptStringEncode`.

Note that it's also a static method on `HttpUtility` - easier to call from a custom helper than making an instance of `AjaxHelper`, but note that unlike `AjaxHelper`, the method on `HttpUtility` returns a simple string, so you'll need to wrap it in an `HtmlString` to avoid HTML encoding.