# JavaScript within Razor with wrong encoding

Tags: c#, javascript, razor

### The goal

Fix the accentuation within `<text>` tag of Razor Engine.

### The problem

I'm brazilian and in our country there are too much accentuation. Apple in our language means "Maçã", and as you can see, there is two accents/special characters.

The follow syntax is written in JavaScript and the application uses Razor Engine for *templating*.

```
var products = [];
@foreach (var product in Model)
{ 
    <text>
        products.push(new Product
                        ("@product.productId",
                         "@product.productName",
                         "@product.thumbnailUrl",
                         "@product.originalProductPrice",
                         "@product.promotionalProductPrice",
                         "@product.measureName",
                         "@product.measureAbbreviation",
                         "@product.marketName",
                         "@product.numberOfMarketsThatHaveThisProduct",
                         "@product.productState")
                );
    </text>
}
```

As you could see, there is Razor within JavaScript and JavaScript within Razor.

One result of this loop is `Maçã` and when I display it within `<text>` tag, the result is: "`Ma&#231;&#227;`".

I really do not know the problem nor how to solve and need your help. **Any ideas?**

Comment: Discussion of similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9167799/1169696

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not at my Windows environment, so I apologize if this is wrong, you'll have to try it:

```
"@Html.Raw(product.productName)",
```

Razor defaults to encoding HTML entities and reserved characters.

Comment: Oh god! Simple answer, huh? Thanks, Andrew. Worked like a charm.

Comment: I will, but you answered more faster than StackOverflow's cop can accept.

Comment: Beware of something like `productName="\"'FooBar quoted'";` :)

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge Ah, forgot about that guy.

Comment: One (somewhat unwieldy) way to avoid the escaping problem with `Html.Raw` would be to use `"@Ajax.JavascriptStringEncode(product.productName)"`, which was made for this very purpose.